# How to synchronize 2 pthreads using mutexes and/or cond vars to create a "guess the number" minigame?

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I am trying to make a "guess the number" minigame to get used to pthreads and synchronization. A thread sleeps for 10 seconds, while the other reads input and says whether the number is too big or too low. When the first thread "wakes up", the second thread should no longer read input, regardless if it were executing scanf. When the second thread has read the correct number, the first thread should no longer sleep and ignore the rest of its code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
unsigned short quit = 0;
unsigned short won = 0;
void * engine(void * arg);
void * arbiter();

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int n = rand() %  100;
    pthread_t t1, t2;
    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, arbiter, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, engine, &n);
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void * arbiter(){
    sleep(10);
    quit = 1;
    printf("Stop!\n");
}

void * engine(void * arg){
    int n = *(int*)arg;
    printf("%d\n", n);
    while(!quit){
        printf("N = ");
        int a;
        scanf("%d", &a);
        if(a < n){
            printf("Go higher!\n");
        } else if(a > n){
            printf("Go lower!\n");
        } else{
            printf("Bingo!\n");
            won = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to use mutexes or cond var here, to make the threads work together. Now, when the first thread wakes up, the second will execute the last scanf. How should I implement this correctly and safe?

Comment: Undefined behavior for unsynchronised, non-atomic, non-readonly access to an object from multiple threads. Also, your description of what to code is supposed to do makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: `should no longer read input, regardless if it were executing scanf.` Sadly `scanf` is a blocking function. Use Posix I/O alternatives, you could use `poll` + `read` to read into a buffer, and then use `sscanf` on that buffer.